# CheckBox UITableView with Different Sections

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to create a UITableview with checkbox button containing different sections, How do i manage to assigning a unique tag for each button in new sections. Since indexpath.row will be repeated in each new section, Cant use indexpath.row

Comment: This is one of the reasons **not** to use tag to identify rows. Instead, you should update your data source when you've "checked the box". That way whenever the tableview re-loads that cell (after scrolling, for example) you can control the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Here is a simple example - it uses a `UISwitch` instead of a "checkbox"... but it will be virtually identical:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369289/swift-3-uiswitch-in-tableviewcell-loses-state-when-scrolling/44370083#44370083

Comment: I have UIButton, UISwitch does have sender.isOn property but what about just a UIButton with background image changing

Comment: I assume you've added some code or property or something to track the state of your UIButton?

Comment: I am a bit confused, in one of your answer you have told to update the datasource and another one to use the Button state, if i use the button state, How do i know which button is tapped i will have to set the unique tag. If i use datasource again how will i know which buttons datasource was tapped inside which section and row ?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were already using a custom "checkbox" button that had a checked / unchecked state. See my answer for an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using a `UIButton` with checked / unchecked background images with an on/off state:

```
//
//  TableWithCheckTableViewController.swift
//  SWTemp2
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class MyCheckTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCheckButton: UIButton!

    var checkedImage = UIImage(named: "Checked")
    var unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "UnChecked")

    var isOn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            myCheckButton.setBackgroundImage(self.isOn ? checkedImage : unCheckedImage, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    var checkTapAction : ((Bool)->Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        self.isOn = !self.isOn

        checkTapAction?(self.isOn)
    }


}

// simple data object
class MyCheckObject: NSObject {
    var theTitle = ""
    var theCheckState = false

    init(_ title: String) {
        theTitle = title
    }
}

class TableWithCheckTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // array of MyObjects
    var myData = [MyCheckObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // just to make it a little easier to see the rows scroll
        tableView.rowHeight = 60

        // create 40 data objects for the table
        for i in 1...40 {
            let d = MyCheckObject("Data Item: \(i)")
            myData.append(d)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCheckTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCheckTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let d = myData[indexPath.row]
        cell.myLabel.text = d.theTitle
        cell.isOn = d.theCheckState

        // set a "Callback Closure" in the cell
        cell.checkTapAction = {
            (isOn) in
            // update our Data Array to the new state of the switch in the cell
            self.myData[indexPath.row].theCheckState = isOn
        }

        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Perfect !!! amazing how this works , No more setting unique tags and unwanted code