# Button in UITableViewCell not staying attached to initial Cell after reload

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a Button in a custom cell which changes image after being pressed, but whenever a reload is triggered the newly added cell has the changed image instead of the old one. This is my cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Sender", for: indexPath) as! Sender
        cell.clearCellData()
        cell.message.text = self.items[indexPath.row].content
        cell.name.text = self.items[indexPath.row].name
        cell.from = self.items[indexPath.row].fromID
        return cell
    }
```

The button's outlet and actions are both in Button cell like this:

```
@IBAction func downVoted(_ sender: Any) {
    if(self.downVote.image(for: .normal) == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DownGray")){
        self.downVote.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DownOn"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        self.downVote.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DownGray"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

It works fine until a new row is added. I have tried setting the buttons tags the same as the cell tags but it didn't help. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to track the "state" of the button along with the rest of your table's data, and then set the proper image in `cellForRowAt`. See my answer at this question for a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393575/checkbox-uitableview-with-different-sections/44398444#44398444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of cells are reused, try to set images in `cellForRowAt:` to do so you need to have a bool(selected or not) in your model, you have to use delegate for touch , and implement it in your controller, so you can change your model at index and reload table view, I provide sample code

```
protocol SenderDelegate {
    func downVoteTapped(_ cell: MainTVCell)
}

class Sender: UITableViewCell {
   @IBAction func downVoted(_ sender: Any) {
      delegate!.downVoteTapped(self)
   }
}
```

and controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Sender", for: indexPath) as! Sender
        cell.clearCellData()
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.message.text = self.items[indexPath.row].content
        cell.name.text = self.items[indexPath.row].name
        cell.from = self.items[indexPath.row].fromID
        if self.items[indexPath.row].selected == true {
           self.downVote.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DownOn"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.downVote.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DownGray"), for: .normal)
        }
        return cell
    }

func downVoteTapped(_ cell: Sender) {
    let index = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row)!
    self.items[index].selected == !self.items[index].selected 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and don't forget to do `SomeViewController: SenderDelegate` 
and in your model `var selected = false`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to setup the state of the button in 
`cellForRowAt indexPath:` delegate method each time it's called.
Therefore you should store the state of the button somewhere, it can be an array or plist.

You have your items stored in the array and I can suggest to add a property to it `var isLiked: Bool`, and you should change that property once the button was pressed, and accords to that property you should either set selected or unselected image in your `cellForRowAt indexPath:` method