# UIButton inside TableViewCell couldn't be set image after clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

Button inside UITableViewCell don't respond to setImage method inside its clicked method. Here is the cellForRowAt section for TableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BroadcastViewCell", for: indexPath) as!BroadcastViewCell
    var show=self.week?[selectedIndex].shows?[indexPath.item]
    cell.myLabel.text=show?.programName
    if let resim=show?.thumbURL{
        cell.myImage.downloadImage(from: resim)
    }
    cell.notifyButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.notifyButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"icnAlarm"), for: .normal)
    cell.notifyButton.setImage( UIImage(named:"icnAlarmCheck"), for: .selected)

    if (self.notifications?.contains(where: {$0.identifier == (show?.airDate)!+(show?.airTime)!}))!
    {
        cell.notifyButton.isSelected=true
    }else
    {
        cell.notifyButton.isSelected=false
    }
    cell.notifyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell;
}
```

And I just set its selected state inside the buttonClicked implementation.

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    sender.isSelected=true
}
```

But the image doesn't change after it. It only changes after cellForRowAt method invocation for its particular row. I don't understand why it responds differently to the same code part. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See my answer to this post - (link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393575/checkbox-uitableview-with-different-sections/44398444#44398444] - It uses two images for a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell` to create a Selected / Un-Selected "CheckBox", which should be really close to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the button what to do:

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    if myButton.isSelected {
         myButton.isSelected = false
    }else{
       myButton.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

configure your button to be custom:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

Or in Attributes Inspector:

[image: attributes Inspector forbutton]

Comment: selected has been renamed to isSelected in my version, also setting isSelected true works expectedly inside cellForRowAt method.

Comment: Question: does your buttonClicked method is triggered at all? and BTW try to set your button type to custom

Comment: Yes, it is triggered. Also, when i open Debug View Hierarchy, i can see the button image changed succesfully. But it doesn't respond to this change in actual device.

Comment: So, the problem is that you can't see the image associated to the button selected status. Did you tried to change your button to .custom? or in interface builder in Attribute inspector -> type -> custom?