# UISwitch added to a tableView is selected when scrolling

Tags: uiswitch, swift4.1

I have embed a UISwitch on a UITableView cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if self.users.count > 0 {
        let eachPost = self.users[indexPath.row]
        let postDate = (eachPost.date as? String) ?? ""
        let postTitle = (eachPost.title as? String) ?? ""

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postDate
        cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle
    }

    if cell.accessoryView == nil{
        let switchView : UISwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
        switchView.setOn(false, animated: true)
        cell.accessoryView = switchView
    }

    return cell
}
```

My table has 30 rows. When I select a switch on the visible cells and then scroll down, on the cells from the bottom of the list the switch is selected by default. What can I do to have correct selections for my list?

Comment: Can you please add full code of your cellForRowAt function?

Comment: You need to store updated switch value for indexPath and set true/false in cellForRow func

Comment: @aBilal17 I've added the full code for cellForRowAt function.

Comment: It's because of reusing. You must save values in some array and set them in cell for row.

Comment: Can you give me more details on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate, please have a look on this url. There is full detailed example for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369289/swift-3-uiswitch-in-tableviewcell-loses-state-when-scrolling/44370083

Answer (score 0):

My solution without creating a custom class:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var users: [[String: Any]] = [[String: Any]]()
// This array is used for storring the state for switch from each cell. Otherwise when the cell is reused the state is displayed incorrectly
    var switchArray = [Bool]()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.users = result
            for _ in 0 ..< self.users.count {
                self.switchArray.append(false)
            }
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let eachPost = self.users[indexPath.row]
    let postTitle = (eachPost.title as? String) ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle

    let switchView : UISwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.isOn = self.switchArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryView = switchView

return cell}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    self.switchArray[indexPath.row] = true
let switchView : UISwitch = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryView) as! UISwitch;
    switchView.isOn = true

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.switchArray[indexPath.row] = false
let switchView : UISwitch = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryView) as! UISwitch;
    switchView.isOn = false
}
```

Note: Multiple selection has to be enabled