# How to use a button in an UITableViewCell to add a TextView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to have a `UITableView` of `UITableViewCells` that include a label of an item with a button next to it. When the table is initially loaded, it just shows the label and button, but when the button is pressed I would like a `textView` to expand and the row height for that one cell is increased.

I'm using interface builder and setting the row height automatically. I'm starting with the `textView` in IB with a height of `0` so I can have the cell height constrained to be 5 from the bottom of the `textView`. My plan was to change the height of the `textView` (`textView.frame.size.height = 100`) and the row height would automatically increase. But that does not happen.

I have looked into a bunch of different ways, but most of my google searching ends with questions about dynamically increasing text height while typing which is not what I want. I would like to post some code, but there are so many different things I have tried (estimated row height, manually setting cell frame, delegates & protocols, `tableView.reloadData()`,  `tableView.recalculateRowHeight()`, manually setting the row height, etc. and haven't gotten much success. If I can get some advice on the best way to do this, I will post some sample code if I am still having trouble. Best case this would be animated, but at this point, I don't need it animated.

I added a GitLab Project link: https://gitlab.com/vever343/expandingrow
(in this sample code I start with a `textView` height of 10, then increase it with the button)

`TableViewController` code:

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, cellProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        } else {
            return TableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func rowExpanded() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

`UITableViewCell` Code:

```
import UIKit

protocol cellProtocol {
    func rowExpanded()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var delegate:MainVC?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        textView.frame.size.height = 100
        delegate?.rowExpanded()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to include some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes I am. I would like to use it, but if for some reason this makes it much more difficult, I am open to changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `NSLayoutConstraint` for your textview height constraint then play with it instead of `textview.frame.size`

```
import UIKit

protocol cellProtocol {
    func rowExpanded()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var delegate:MainVC?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {    
          self.layoutIfNeeded()   
          self.delegate?.rowExpanded()
        }   

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And for the animation part,

```
func rowExpanded() {
   self.tableView.beginUpdates()  
   self.tableView.endUpdates() 
}
```

Update: If you want it keep textview state when tableview is scrolled, you should also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369289/swift-3-uiswitch-in-tableviewcell-loses-state-when-scrolling) example.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for embedding the solution into the code and even linking to the article to keep state. The extra effort is appreciated!

Comment: @KevinVeverka Does it update the row height as well? It doesn't for me...

Comment: @RevanthKausikan you must be sure about bottom and top constraint relative to cell's content view if you are using `UITableView.automaticDimension`.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html
_"To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content view’s top edge and its bottom edge"_

Comment: @ocanal, yes I am depending on the intrinsic content size. I don't think that is the problem. My `rowExpanded()` isn't getting called at all, because `var delegate:MainVC?` holds null. I'm new to swift, please pardon me if it is something obvious.

Comment: @RevanthKausikan, did you set delegate in `cellForRowAt`,  `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: Oh yes! That was the mistake. Thank you so much @ocanal

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tableview height for row at like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40  // this can be an estimated value you choose
}
```

make sure your textview's alignment is set to natural.
When the button is hit, reload the tableview

Comment: Jaelee, thank you for the comment.  This is something I found a lot online and was one of many things I tried.  The row height doesn't change when I press the button. I added sample code using your direction and published it on GitLab.
https://gitlab.com/vever343/expandingrow (in this sample code I start with a `textView` height of 10, then increase it with the button)

Comment: Is the functionality on Gitlab the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I updated Gitlab with ocanal's solution in case others are having the same problem. I needed to setup the NSLayoutConstraint to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Ocanal's answer is correct, but I found another way of doing it while I was continuing on in my development that is a bit easier.  If you put all of the items in a `StackView` then you can use `stackView.isHidden` and Auto Layout will automatically take care of the row height if it is constrained properly.